# Creating an addContact() method that will create unique contacts each time

Tags: java, object, unique

A school assignment (in beginner Java) is asking me to create a small contact manager program, which I'm having trouble with.

It asks us to create a few classes - Address, PhoneNumber, Contact, and ContactManager.

In ContactManager, we're asked to create a method called addContact() which will add a brand new unique contact to an object array within ContactManager.

However I cannot figure out how to make this method do what I want it to do since each time it creates a new Contact, it always has the same name. How do I make the object it creates have a unique name (i.e. Contact001, Contact002 etc) each time?

Also, how do I feed through all the relevant information it needs to create it, assuming I can enter all the data in instance variables to test it?
This is my code class:

```
public class Contact {
//Contact Instance Variables
private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private Address completeAddress[];
private PhoneNumber phoneNumer[];
private SocialNetworkAccount socialNetworkInfo[];



public Contact(String lastName, String firstName, String middleName,
        Address[] completeAddress, PhoneNumber[] phoneNumer,
        SocialNetworkAccount[] socialNetworkInfo) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.completeAddress = completeAddress;
    this.phoneNumer = phoneNumer;
    this.socialNetworkInfo = socialNetworkInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"private List contacts;"  is a declaration of an instance variable called contacts.

The variable's type is a List, which is a specific kind of Collection object found in the java.util package.

List`<Contact>` is a way of stating to the compiler that this list contains only Contact objects.  See "Generics" in the java tutorial.

Comment: We've just started talking about generics now.

Answer (score 0):

In your ContactManager class, define these

```
private List<Contact> contacts; 

contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>(); //you should put this in ContactManager constructor

public void addContact(Contact contact) {
 contacts.add(contact);
}
```

When you want to add a new contact

```
//just supply different names, etc. load the information from a file
contactManager.addContact(new Contact(name,surname,....));
```

or...

To add a couple of placeholder contacts...

```
int NUM_OF_CONTACTS = 2; //how many contacts to create
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_CONTACTS; ++i) {
 contactManager.addContact(new Contact(("Contact" + i),"Placeholder Surname",..);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain "private List<Contact> contacts;"?

I've never seen it before...